# how to fully use value_count function in python

Tags: python, pandas

Using Python value_count() in order to figure out frequent occurrences of words in a column. There's a lot of words and the function is only showing the most and the least frequent occurrences. How do I make the it show the entire list of counts of values so I can see what's not showing?

Comment: first you post your function ... or just use `collections.Counter(my_text_corpus)` oh you are using `pandas`? and `value_counts`?  I think pandas "helpfully" truncates what it shows you ...  you need to convert it `tolist()`

Comment: Show the code you are using! value_count() does not do this as deflaut

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're talking about `pd.options.display.max_rows` default option...

Just do the following:

```
pd.options.display.max_rows = 10000
```

and run `value_counts()` again:

```
df['column'].value_counts()
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you!

Comment: Sure! Thanks for the heads up I'm rather new here.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is correct but it will change it permanently if you use it in Jupyter Notebook cell. If you want to temporary change it to take effect only on this step as in unique cell from Jupyter Notebook, please consider this:

```
with pd.option_context("display.max_rows", None):
    display(df['column'].value_counts())
```